# How to find the reason for locked accounts in Active Directory?

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2022, sophos

Help me figure out why Active Directory locks accounts who connect to the corporate network via VPN (l2tp).

**Given**:

1. local Windows Server 2022 with the latest updates + Active Directory + file storage (samba)
2. Sophos XG 310 firewall, which acts as a gateway and VPN server
3. client machines with Windows 10 Pro

A user logged on to a machine with their AD account connects to a VPN server. The AD domain pings, but when accessing a network resource, the account is locked out.

The server logs contain information about the account being locked out, but there is no information why. On the client logs there is information about winlogon.exe being locked due to an incorrectly entered password. Sometimes you can get normal access to network drives if, after connecting to the VPN, you log out of Windows and log in again. This is not always possible and the account is also locked when you try to log in again.

When working with network resources on a local network or from a remote network in which the router has previously established VPN connections (thus creating a tunnel), accounts are not locked out. Network folders are mounted automatically using GPO depending on the user group. The rule in the GPO that could lockout users is disabled. The account is not locked out if the password is entered incorrectly (value 0). Server auditing is enabled; GPO rule for periodic password changes is disabled; Passwords in the password manager on client machines were deleted.

*p.s. The AD server was moved 1.5 years ago from Windows 2003 to Windows 2008, and then to Windows 2022. Users connected to the VPN server using the pptp protocol. Then the protocol was replaced by l2tp for greater security and encryption of the tunnels.*

**Addition**: I found strange errors in the event log on the server. Before the test account is locked out, event 4769 with code 0x18 (Pre-authentication information was invalid) appears in the logs, indicating unsuccessful authorization using the Kerberos protocol, indicating the IP address of the old network that was disconnected from before connecting to the VPN. The authorization type (logon type) is 3 (network connection, as when opening a shared folder). It seems that the account is locked out at the moment of switching from one network with Internet access to another. There is no information about which application is causing the lockouts. All PIDs and TIDs in the logs point to lsaas.exe.

This is followed by a bunch of similar events 4625 with code 0xC0000234 (user is currently locked out) with a new IP address issued by the vpn server. These events differ only in port. It’s as if there is a search and an attempt to connect, but using the NTLM protocol.

Today I noticed another strange thing: if you try to enter the password incorrectly 6 times, the user’s account is locked out even on the local network. Although the lockout threshold in the GPO rules is set to 0 (never lock out).

I tried changing the lockout threshold to 999 attempts to enter an incorrect password and the lockout time to 2 minutes. It seems that these rules do not apply at all, because... again, after 6 attempts to enter the password incorrectly, the account was locked out, and after 2 or even 5 minutes it did not unlock itself. Gpresult and local rules indicate that the configuration is being pulled from the domain. But for some reason it doesn’t apply!

**How to find the reason for account lockouts?**

Comment: `But for some reason it doesn’t apply!` AD only uses the password and account policy settings in the Default Domain Policy.

Comment: @GregAskew I have activated Default Domain Policy on my controller. In GPO policy `Computer Configuration->Policies->Security Settings->Account Policies->Account Lockout Policy` i have a rule: `Account blocking threshold` with a value of 0, which means "never block".